# Filter a nested array column and create new nested array column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a below sample data frame, where I need to filter colA based on the contents of field colB

```
Schema for the Input

 |-- colA: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- colB: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

| colA                                  | colB           |
| ------------------------------------- | -------------- |
| [{ABC, Completed}, {DEF, Pending}]    | [ABC, GHI]     |
| [{ABC, Completed}, {GHI, Failure}]    | [ABC, GHI]     |
| [{ABC, Completed}, {DEF, Pending}]    | [ABC]          |
```

So, looking for below output

```
| colA                              | colB       | colC   
| ----------------------------------| -----------| ------
| [{ABC, Completed}, {DEF, Pending}]| [ABC, GHI] | [{ABC, Completed}]
| [{ABC, Completed}, {GHI, Failure}]| [ABC, GHI] | [{ABC, Completed}, {GHI, Failure}]
| [{ABC, Completed}, {DEF, Pending}]| [ABC]      | [{ABC, Completed}]
```

I was able to figure out the logic using higher-order functions when the colB is a String. Below is a code snippet for it, need help to expand it to when colB is array of strings

```
inputDF
      .withColumn(
        "colC",
        expr(
          "filter(colA, colA_struct -> colA_struct.id == colB)"
        )
      )
```

Comment: can you share schema of the dataframe containing the data (not the output)

Comment: @VikasSaxena Done, added the input Schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `array_contains` function to determine whether `colB` contains `colA.id`, and then use the `filter` function to filter `colA`, that is You can get `colC`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
......
df = df.withColumn('colC', F.expr('filter(colA, x -> array_contains(colB, x.id))'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```